# Worklight showIOS7StatusBar

Tags: ios7, ibm-mobilefirst, statusbar

I am running the Worklight IDE Version 6.0.0.20130926-1933.  I have tried disabling the ios7 top status bar as per the Worklight technote found here:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27039574

I have set in the initOptions.js file

```
var wlInitOptions = {
    
    // # Should application automatically attempt to connect to Worklight Server on application start up
    // # The default value is true, we are overriding it to false here.
    connectOnStartup : true,
    showIOS7StatusBar : false,
```

However, when I load my app I still see the statusBar displayed on my iOS7 devices.  Is there some other change I need to make to my code?  Note:  I don't have access to xCode and I am using a company tool to build the ipa file.  Thanks!

JT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also change it in the {AppName}-Info.plist in your IOS native directory

```
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
    <key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
    <true/>
```

Comment: Thanks... changing the plist file removed the status bar.  Thanks again!

Comment: Problem with this, is when i start the application in landscape it seems the width is set as if in portrait

Answer (score 1):

Did you do a build of the application in Worklight and in Xcode and you still see it?
Anyway, you can add to your CSS file:

```
#wl_ios7bar {
    display:none;
}
```

and you will not see it anymore.

Comment: Hi Ravidor,  modifying my css file in my iphone folder didn't change the behavior for me, but perhaps there is some other action that I need to take.  The plist alternative did the trick.  I don't have access to Xcode (we're using Build Forge to generate the ipa file).  I am rebuilding the app in Worklight.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is in the main.css or equivalent file of the iPhone environment specifically, override the application css with the code like:

```
.ios7 
{ 
 margin-top: 17px !important; 
}
```

And in the main.js or equivalent file of the iPhone environment, 
override the js file with the code like:

```
function wlEnvInit(){ 
wlCommonInit(); // Environment initialization code goes here
if (parseFloat(window.device.version) >= 7.0) { 
 $("body").addClass("ios7"); 
  }
 }
```

You can also check the [reference link](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/28737/status-bar-overlap-on-an-ios-device.html)